# Position the confirmation box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using the jquery plugin : [confirmon](https://github.com/invetek/jquery-confirmon)

I would like to find a way to position this confirmation box dynamically.

But the classic jquery way is not working :

```
$('.confirmon-box').css('top','800');
```

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried with `px` after 800?  `.css("top", "800px");`  If you put 800 without quotes then it assumes pixels, but if you put it in quotes it assumes you did it right ;)

Comment: Tried with and without px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no alternatives are available, changed from plugin, using a more customizable now: [Zebra_Dialog](https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Dialog/)